How to manage visibility and enabled state of overlapping buttons in a ConstraintLayout?
I have two buttons in a ConstraintLayout in my Android application: startButton and stopButton. Both buttons have the same constraints, so they are positioned on top of each other. When the activity starts, I want only the startButton to be visible and clickable, while the stopButton should be invisible.
I'm currently using the following code to achieve this:
startButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
stopButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

My question is:

Is it necessary to also set the isEnabled property for both buttons, like this?

startButton.setEnabled(true);
stopButton.setEnabled(false);


If setting isEnabled is necessary, why is it required?

I want to ensure that startButton is visible and clickable, and stopButton is completely hidden and not clickable when the activity starts.
Layout XML:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Java Code:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button startButton;
    private Button stopButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startButton = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        stopButton = findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

        startButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        stopButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        // Optional:
        // startButton.setEnabled(true);
        // stopButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

Initial State: startButton should be visible and clickable and  stopButton should be invisible and not clickable.
Do I need to explicitly set the isEnabled property for both buttons, or is managing the visibility (View.VISIBLE and View.INVISIBLE) sufficient for my requirements? Any detailed explanation or best practices would be appreciated.

Instead of setting stopButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); you can also set stopButton.setVisibility(View.GONE).
When setting View.GONE the constraints are eased and the element "disappears". You can check this in layout view. When changing you can again set stopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE). Using this method the isEnabled should not be necessary.
Another option is to only use one button and instead of changing visibility you could also change the onClick parameter as well as the text parameter based on whether start or stop is desired.

Okay, but If I use View.GONE, it also impact other constraints, I am specifically focussing on View.INVISIBLE and isEnabled=false.

In that case the solution is to change the text and onClick parameter of one button instead of using two buttons. Because Visibility.INVISIBLE makes the button invisible and disables it, but the button still takes space in the UI. Thus if the top button is invisible and disabeld, the bottom button is visible but can not be clicked as the invisible button blocks the interaction. If you definetly need to have two buttons try working with another invisible widget under both buttons and set the constraints to this. Then you should be able to use Visibility.GONE

Answer to 1st question: No it is not neccesary to use button.setEnabled(true) as they are enabled by default.
As @Pabart13 said you should make the view as View.GONE ads if you use View.INVISIBLE the view is still there and will be functional but not visible.
As constraints are concerned you can use guidelines to manage the view behavior after a view is set to View.GONE.
But the second approach is really simple i.e to manage both button functionality with only one button. hence it will be easy and reduce load of the app.
You can do that as follows :
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if(button.getText().toString() == "Start"){
                 button.setText("Stop");
                 //Do other operation you want to do with start button.
               }
               else {
                 button.setText("Start");
                 // Do other operations you want to do with stop button.
               }
            }
        });

These are the two methods, guideline is a way but it would be complicated so I would advice to use just one button and manage it.
